# Clarify about direct image and inverse image (of morphisms of sheaves)

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Suppose to have a continuous function $\alpha:X\to Y$ between topological spaces, and suppose to have two sheaves, $\mathcal F$ defined on $X$ and $\mathcal G$ defined on $Y$. It's well known how are defined the direct image $\alpha_*\mathcal F$, also called pushforward, and the inverse image $\alpha^{-1}\mathcal G$, also called pullback. Clearly, any open set in $Y$ containing $\alpha(x)$ must be of the form $\alpha (U)$ for some open $U\subset X$ containing $x$; in fact, $(\alpha^{-1}\mathcal G)_x$ is equal to $\mathcal G_{\alpha (x)}$.

My problem is that I don't understand why, fixed $x\in X$, in general $(\alpha_*\mathcal F)_x$ is not equal to $(\mathcal F)_x$. I understand that the open sets of the form $\alpha ^{-1}(V)$, with $V\subset Y$ open set containing $\alpha (x)$, are not all the open set of $X$ containing $x$, however the equivalence classes in $(\mathcal F)_x$ seem to me to be all covered by $(\alpha_*\mathcal F)_x$. What I mean is that, for any section $f\in \mathcal F(U)$, with $U\subset X$ an open set containing $x$ that is not preimage of an open of $Y$, one could take $V\subset Y$ open, containing $\alpha (x)$, and consider the restriction of $f$ to $W:=\alpha ^{-1} (V)$. So $f_x=(f|_W)_x\in(\alpha_*\mathcal F)_x$. Where is the  contradiction \ misunderstanding in my reasoning? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write:

> Clearly, any open set in $Y$ containing $\alpha(x)$ must be of the form $\alpha(U)$ for some open $U\subset X$ containing $x$.

That's not true. There's no reason why sets of the form $\alpha(U)$ should even be open, and $\alpha(x)$ may have many many open neighborhoods in $Y$ which are not images of open neighborhoods of $x$.

You also write:

> For any section $f\in \mathcal F(U)$, with $U\subset X$ an open set containing $x$ that is not preimage of an open of $Y$, one could take $V\subset Y$ open, containing $\alpha (x)$, and consider the restriction of $f$ to $W:=\alpha ^{-1} (V)$.

To do this, we would have to have $\alpha^{-1}(V)\subset U$. Why do you think that such a $V$ must exist?

Comment: For your first correction, I'm not sure to understand. Having $\alpha:X\to Y $ continuous, if I fix $x\in X$, and I take an open set $V\subset Y$ containing $\alpha(x)$, the preimage $U:=\alpha^{-1}(V)$ must be open in $X$ and must contain $x$ by definition. Also, $\alpha(U)=V$. For your second correction, I think I understand: for example, if I take the canonical projection $\pi:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$, an open disk in $\mathbb R^2$ doesn't contain any preimage of an open set  in $\mathbb R$, right? ($\pi$ is defined $(x,y)\mapsto x$). Thank you

Comment: First point: In general, $\alpha(\alpha^{-1}(V))\neq V$. Think about the inclusion $\mathbb{R}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ as the $x$-axis: no non-empty open set in $\mathbb{R}$ has open image in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Second point: Yes, that counterexample is correct.

Comment: Ok, so for the first point I should say first that there exist an open set $V\subset \alpha(X)\subset Y$ containing $\alpha (x)$, and that the stalk of $\mathcal G$ at $\alpha( x)$ is the same as the stalk of $\mathcal G|_V$ at $\alpha( x)$. Then I can say that every open set in $V$ containing $\alpha( x)$ is of the form $\alpha( U)$ for some open set $U\subset X$ containing $x$, right?

Comment: Sure, that's true. But two comments:  (1) For any sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ on $Y$ and any $y\in V\subseteq Y$ with $V$ open, $\mathcal{G}_y = (\mathcal{G}|_V)_y$. So that hypothesis isn't necessary. (2) It's true in general that for any continuous $\alpha\colon X\to Y$, any sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ on $Y$, and any $x\in X$ that $(\alpha^{-1}\mathcal{G})_x = \mathcal{G}_{\alpha(x)}$. So you should prove this in general, rather than assuming that there is some open $V$ with $\alpha(x)\in V\subseteq\alpha(X)$.